# MySQL Re-use Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, subquery

I've read a few threads here on subquery re-use, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer to my problem: Assuming the following table **temp** (in MySQL):

```
+------+---+----+
| Y    | M | V  |
+------+---+----+
| 1995 | 0 |  3 |
| 1995 | 1 | 16 |
| 1995 | 4 | 18 |
| 2025 | 0 |  4 |
| 2025 | 2 | 13 |
+------+---+----+
```

I'd like to generate a new column X, which copies V from a row where M is 0 into all rows with the same Y(ear), e.g.:

```
+------+---+----+------+
| Y    | M | V  | X    |
+------+---+----+------+
| 1995 | 0 |  3 |    3 |
| 1995 | 1 | 16 |    3 |
| 1995 | 4 | 18 |    3 |
| 2025 | 0 |  4 |    4 |
| 2025 | 2 | 13 |    4 |
+------+---+----+------+
```

This can be done like this:

```
SELECT Y, M, V,
  (SELECT V FROM temp WHERE temp.Y = t.Y AND M = 0) AS X
FROM temp t;
```

or like this:

```
SELECT temp.Y, temp.M, temp.V, q2.V AS X
FROM temp
JOIN (SELECT * FROM temp WHERE M = 0) q2 USING (Y);
```

For purposes of this exercise it can be assumed that **temp** contains only one M = 0 for each Y(ear).

Trouble is, that **temp** isn't really a table, but the result of a complex query.  Replacing temp with the actual query is unwieldy, and performance will probably be poor, unless MySQL is smart enough to detect that the two constructs are identical.

Given no WITH clause in MySQL, is there a way to generate X without the need to refer to **temp** twice; i.e. is a subquery really needed for this problem?

The code will eventually run inside a S-PROC, so I could create a temporary memory table, but I wonder if there's a more *elegant* solution.

Comment: As you have discovered, mysql does not support Common Table Expressions how ever what you are trying to achieve maybe possible with nested subqueries.

Comment: would a view help, it's not a table, but acts as one in queries

Comment: Thx. I've limited experience with views. Not sure if they can take variables as the complex query is parameter driven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common table expressions and subqueries are the easiest way.  A view is one solution.  Another is to use variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@v := if(@y = y, @v,
                 if(@y := y, v, v)
                )
       )
from temp t cross join
     (select @y := 0, @v := -1) params
order by year, (m = 0) desc;
```

Note that this formulation makes a strong assumption that each year has at least one value of `m = 0` -- it copies the first value encountered for each year for all the rows for that year.  You specify that this is true in the description of the problem.  The expression can be made a bit more complicated to cover the situation where a year does not have such a row (but that would be a different question).

Comment: Thx, this works and looks promising as temp appears only once.  I need to get my head around what is actually going on an :-)

BTW, order is not essential for this problem.

Comment: @Matthias . . . `orer by` is needed for the logic to work.  It needs to find `m = 0` for a given year before the other values of `m` for that year.

Comment: Good to know, thx Gordon.  Incidentally the physical order produces ordered Ys with leading m=0, but that may not always be the case, and important for anybody else re-using this elegant solution.  (Still haven't worked out why this works the way it does, because I need to adapt it to the actual problem, where I need to match more than just Y, and more than one V(alue) must be copied from the M=0 row. :-)